# I am new to react, I have a query in following code in VS studio in importing a function

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio

I am not able to import function Navbar, I get a blank output but if I try to build the function in file.js it works so there should be error in how I import it. Any advice? in Here are my 3 files:
navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar(){
    return<nav className="Navbar">
        <a href="/" className="site-title">
            Hello name of the site
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/pricing_option1">Pricing_option1</a>
                <a href="/pricing_option2">pricing_option2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylsheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="file.js" type="text/babel" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file.js

```
import Navbar from "./navbar"



ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <Navbar />
  </div>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```
Output: blank
```

if I try to build the function in file.js it works so there should be error in how I import it.

Answer (score 0):

NavBar.js:

```
import React from "react";
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="Navbar">
      <a href="/" className="site-title">
        Hello name of the site
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/pricing_option1">Pricing_option1</a>
          <a href="/pricing_option2">pricing_option2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="file.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Navbar from "./navbar";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Navbar />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I made all three files as per your code, still vs code live server is blank output. Could you please explain where is the mistake in above code in question.

Comment: Try my new updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Delete export default function Navbar

Insert export default Navbar; on the bottom of your file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).